# What are VB-Specific IDE features in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I use both VB and C# for .NET programming. It is always interesting to see VB specific IDE enhancements and features.

I want to know all possible VB-Specific features in Visual Studio 2013 IDE.

Both VB and C# programmers are encouraged to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are VB Specific options in Visual Studio 2013.

**Automatic insertion of end constructs:**

When you type—for example, the first line of a procedure declaration, Sub Main—and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the text editor adds a matching End Sub line. Similarly, if you add a For loop, the text editor adds a matching Next statement. When this option is selected, the code editor automatically adds the end construct.

**Pretty listing (reformatting) of code:**

The text editor reformats your code as appropriate. When this option is selected, the code editor will:

- Align your code to the correct tab position
- Recase keywords, variables, and objects to the correct case
- Add a missing Then to an If...Then statement
- Add parenthesis to function calls
- Add missing end quotes to strings
- Reformat exponential notation
- Reformat dates

**Enable outlining mode:**

When you open a file in the code editor, you can view the document in outlining mode. When this option is selected, the outlining feature is activated when you open a file.

**Automatic insertion of Interface and MustOverride members:**

When you commit an Implements statement or an Inherits statement for a class, the text editor inserts prototypes for the members that have to be implemented or overridden, respectively.

**Show procedure line separators:**

The text editor indicates visual scope of procedures. A line is drawn in the .vb source files is drawn to show the separation.

**Enable error correction suggestion:**

The text editor can suggest solutions to common errors and allow you to select the appropriate correction, which is then applied to your code.

**Enable highlighting of references and keywords:**

The text editor can highlight all instances of a symbol or all of the keywords in a clause such as If..Then, While...End While, or Try...Catch...Finally. You can navigate between highlighted references or keywords by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP ARROW</kbd>.

Here is screenshot:

[image: vb specific options]

And here is detailed explanation of these settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0y5th94.aspx